# Disabling "Remember My Password" prompt to users visiting site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have an ASP.Net MVC site and I was wondering if it was possible at all to make it so users will have to enter in their passwords manually so its not auto filled for them by the browser? It seems like a simple thing to ask, but googling this I just get instructions on how a client can disable their prompt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've never used it for this, but there is an autocomplete property that when disabled will tell the browser not to store any information from the password field :

> If AutoComplete is disabled, values
>   are not stored and suggested values
>   are not presented.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx

```
<INPUT TYPE="password" AUTOCOMPLETE="off">
```

I've used it for normal text fields for credit card numbers and such.  But I didn't realize this would work for the password fields as well. You might want to try it in other browsers besides IE though to be sure.

UPDATE: Looks like this works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly set `value=""` It will not be remembered. This is how my bank does it. You can also set the autocomplete property.