# Reset login page after i gave safe your password asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reset

Have an aspx page for Login. I have textboxes for username, password and a label to indocate on invalid logins. Have a Reset button which on click should clear the textboxes and label. Everytihing is functioning good normally. But when i gave browser to remember password, the reset click loads the page with the remembered username and password. I need to reset page even after i remember the password.

code in reset button:

```
protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
        lblErrorMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Have updated with the code

Comment: username and password not clear or password only not clear

Comment: previous value is clear by both username and password textbox is loaded with save credential value

Comment: IsPostback in your page load event

Comment: Thanks Senthil.. I did it using jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `autocomplete="off"` as follows

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" autocomplete="off" runat="server"/>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" autocomplete="off" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
```

The setting can be done at the client side. From the server side you don't have more options.

1. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/768930
2. [Disabling "Remember My Password" prompt to users visiting site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322567/disabling-remember-my-password-prompt-to-users-visiting-site)

Answer (score 0):

Accomplished reset form using jquery

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-reset").click(function () {
            $('.login-block').find('input:text').val('');
            $('.login-block').find('input:password').val('');
            $('#lblErrorMessage').text('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for all comments and answers.